# Statistics error limit on a fitting

Tags: nuclear-physics, computational-physics, error-analysis, software, data-analysis

We are trying to analyze gamma-ray spectra that come from a neutron scattering in the soil sample. Our hope is to find the final error in the fitting parameters of the peak, which should look like a gaussian shape. We expect to have a low count (s) of the actual signal on top of a background (b).

From a simple calculation, error on the signal will be $\sqrt(s + 2b)$ (as in the second half of this post). I am wondering if this is the lowest limit of the error estimation for signal s. If so, when s is small, our error can be larger than the value s. If anyone has a thought on this, whether a confirmation that this is a correct statement and/or a way to calculate errors without being affected by the background value, I would love to hear about it. Thanks!

The calculation and MWE for the signal s that lead to this question is as follows:

#### Adding two Poissonian results in a new Poissonian

Given $p(i; \mu_1)$ and $p(j; \mu_2)$ we can calculate a new distribution

$$ p(n; \lambda) = \sum^n_{l=0} p(l; \mu_1) p(n-l; \mu_2) $$

which one can simplify to

$$ p(n; \lambda) = \frac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^k}{k!}\, e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}  $$

So $\lambda=\mu_1+\mu_2$ and the sum is still Poissonian distributed and therefore the error is $\sqrt{\mu_1+\mu_2}$

#### Difference of two Poissonian

The difference of two Poissonian has a special distribution, the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution).

The mean of the Skellam distribution $\mu_1-\mu_2$ and the variance is $\mu_1+\mu_2$.

#### Application

This has direct application for gamma spectra. If we look at a energy histogram in a gamma measurement, we often have a background signal (b) and a signal (s). Both will be Poissonian distributed. Therefore the sum of both will also be Poissonian with a mean and variance of $s+b$.

If we measure this number and can estimate a background (say from neighboring channels), we can subtract the background out, but this will result in a Skellam distribution and therefore we get:

mean:  $(s+b)-b = s$

variance:  $(s+b)+b = s+2b$  therefore the error is $\sqrt{s+2b}$.

```
N = 10_000

mu_s = 100
mu_b = 100

measurement = np.random.poisson(mu_s+mu_b, size=N)
background = np.random.poisson(mu_b, size=N)

signal = measurement-background
# need to make sure we get one bin for each integer to avoid binning artifects
plt.hist(signal, bins=120, range=(40, 160))
mu = signal.mean()
sigma = signal.std()
plt.axvline(mu, color="red")
plt.axvline(mu+sigma, color="green")
plt.axvline(mu-sigma, color="green")
plt.xlabel('measured-background')

print(f"measured: {mu} +- {sigma}")
print(f"   sqrt(mu_s+mu_b) = {np.sqrt(mu_s+mu_b)}  <-- understimates")
print(f"   sqrt(mu_s+2*mu_b) = {np.sqrt(mu_s+2*mu_b)}")
```

Output:

```
measured: 99.9346 +- 17.360861811557626
   sqrt(mu_s+mu_b) = 14.142135623730951  <-- understimates
   sqrt(mu_s+2*mu_b) = 17.320508075688775
```

[image]

Comment: The variance of your background estimate is not $b$ if it has been estimated from channel**s**.

Comment: Please clarify what data you have and how $b$ is estimated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a particle physisics, however, I believe you are using the wrong tools to subtract the background. What you are doing is the following:

1. You measure the background distribution and calculate $\lambda_{background}$,
2. you use this calculated $\lambda_{background}$ and simulate random numbers from the Poisson distribution. This yields a density distribution, which possesses uncertainty.
3. you subtract the simulated density distribution from the measured density distribution. As you have "two random number" in every bin, the uncertainty increases.

I'm pretty sure that step 2 is incorrect. You should not draw random numbers from the Poisson distribution. Instead, you should work with the probability density distribution. This distribution is a well-defined mathematical function. By using this function, we do not obtain an uncertainty. Therefore, subtracting the background from the measured signal does not increase the uncertainty. Does this make sense?

Here my simulated data, to explain how I would do it:

[image]
The graph displays the background data
$X_1 \sim Pois(\lambda=70)$, the (in the experiment unknown) signal
$X_2 \sim Pois(\lambda=100)$, and the combination of the background data and the signal,
$X_{total} = X_1 + X_2$. First, I fit the background data and obtain

```
Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
       estimate Std. Error
lambda  70.2215  0.1873785
```

Next, I fit the total data and obtain

```
Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
       estimate Std. Error
lambda   170.41  0.2918989
```

Therefore, the point estimate of the signal data is
$E[X_2] = E[X_{total}] - E[X_1] = 170.41 - 70.22 = 100.19$, and its uncertainty is given by
$\sqrt{Var[X_{total}] + Var[X_1]} = \ldots = 0.34$.

Comment: Thank you. So, how you would do it is fit the total and the background separately, obtain the errors individually, then get the error for the signal from the variance of the two. Our case is that we have a gaussian shaped signal peak on top of a linear background. From your approach, I guess I would have to fit the linear background from the sides of the gaussian peak to obtain the bkg variance, then.

Comment: Another question for your calculation is, why is the std error not sqrt(70) or sqrt(170)?

Comment: This can't be right. You cannot estimate the signal with a variance that is smaller than 100 and a standard deviation smaller than 10.

Comment: @ProfRob: I use Poisson distributions. Therefore, $\lambda = E[X] = Var[X]$. The last line is *not* estimating the standard deviation of $X_2$, but denotes the **standard error** of $E[X_2]$. To write $Sd[E[X_2]]$ would be formally correct, but I doubt that it does not help to get the idea across.

Comment: You can't estimate the uncertainty in 100 measured counts to be any less than 10.

Comment: I do not claim that my dataset consists of $N=100$ data points. The parameter $\lambda$ is a **rate**, and not the total number of counts.

Comment: @SaraS: The method I describe is simple and straight forward. If you want to go fancy, you probably should fit everything together, and use well-informed Bayesian prior distributions. Cern uses such fits. They do not fit each component separately, because this increases the uncertainty. Therefore, you have to decide how complicated you need to fit your data and which amount of precision you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said how you are estimating $b$. The implication from your $\sqrt{s + 2b}$ result is that you measure source plus background in one channel and background in one other channel. In which case I think your result is correct (at least in a frequentist interpretation, with no prior information about $s$ and $b$).

I would have thought it more likely that your information about $b$ comes from measurements in several ($N$) channels, in which case, the variance in this would not be $b$, it would be $b/N$.

A better (Bayesian) method would be to forward-model the observed source plus background and background channels, calculating the (log) likelihood for each combination of $s$ and $b$ producing the observed data. To this you would add the log of the prior probabilities for $s$ and $b$ -maybe flat, but not allowing either $s$ or $b$ to be less than zero (your current method and error bar does allow $s<0$). The anti-log of the resultants would give the posterior probability distributions for $s$ and $b$.

Comment: I don't think the variance on the background should be $b/N$. When they measure the $\gamma$-ray spectra, they bin their measurements with respect to energy, and therefore measurements for each bin should be independent, as this is the underlying idea of Poissonian distribution which is just some approximations done on multinomial distribution. Anyway, they can estimate the background in the bin in question, but its variance should obey Poissonian again, and thus the variance becomes simply $b$.

Comment: We only estimate that the background in our case looks like a linear function (our spectra would look like gaussian looking peaks plus linear background). We don't really estimate the background.

Comment: @SaraS "We don't really estimate the background." But your questions says - "If we measure this number and can estimate a background (say from neighboring channels)"

Comment: @KaanGüven It is possible I am missing some essential information. When you have a signal sitting on top of a background then you can usually estimate the background level much better than the variance in one pixel, i.e., $b/N$ where $N$ is the number of pixels you have averaged over (assuming they are independent). This variance must be added to $s+b$, the variance in the bin containing your signal plus background. If that is not how the background is estimated, then those details need to be supplied.

Comment: @ProfRob maybe you think of downsampling an image. In that case $b/N$ variance makes sense. However I doubt what they do is anything related to pixels, or any kind of downsampling. I guess what they do is just sideband subtraction. However, if you think that averaging over pixels, or energy bins might be beneficial, I have no knowledge on that, but seems like an interesting idea if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is widely-known and called the 'on-off problem' and occasionally within astrophysics as the Li & Ma problem owing to the paper:

*T. P. Li and Y. Q. Ma. Analysis methods for results in gamma-ray astronomy.
Astrophys. J., 272:317–324, 1983*

A good starting point for reading more on this might be

*A comparison of limit setting methods for the on–off problem
Wolfgang A. Rolke
Nucl.Instrum.Meth.A 806 (2016) 318-324
[1505.07027 [physics.data-an]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07027.pdf)*

That paper reviews limit setting in a frequentist context. There are other papers with Bayesian treatments and that focus on discoveries. You can browse this search to see some of the other physics literature on the topic (NB sometimes it is written on-off and sometimes on/off):

https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=ft%20%22on-off%20problem%22%20or%20ft%20%22on%2Foff%20problem%22